# Vanishing questions

Tags: support, ignored-tags

For the last few days I've seen questions in the front page that appear much fainter than the rest. I had seen such things in other sites with questions or answers that were heavily downvoted, but this does not appear to be the case for the questions where I'm seeing this now. Is there any explanation?

Here is an example:

---

[image: Example]

---

---

Update: As Martin suggested in a comment, this is caused by tags that were somehow in my "ignored" list. However, unlike the screenshot in his link, I do not have such a list on the sidebar on the right of the screen. Any ideas why?

Comment: The link seems to go to a review from Math Reviews, not to anything at MO.

Comment: *Sigh* Thanks, Gerry. I'll see what happened and add the correct link back.

Comment: Do you have some tags among your [ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/ignored-tags/info)? (Perhaps added by mistake.) "Questions with these tags are then dimmed or removed entirely from question lists." (This depends on the user's preferences.) More details on this: [What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173)

Comment: @Martin That is probably it. Do you know how to see one's list of ignored tags? (Mine should be empty, but apparently is not.)

Comment: (@Gerry The correct link has been added. Apologies for the original mix-up.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo As explained in the above links, there are several places to see them. But the most accessible seems to be the list of ignored tags displayed in the sidebar on the right (when viewing [the list of questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions)). I will add link to this question - not because it is related to yours, but mainly because it has a screenshot showing where the ignored tags are displayed: [Updating favorite/ignored tags on tagged questions page messes up formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116030).

Comment: @Martin Hmm. Yes, that's what was confusing me. My sidebar does not include ignored tags, so I figured I didn't have any. Why don't you post the comment as an answer? (Why I do not have the list of ignored tags displayed on the sidebar seems a different issue altogether.)

Comment: (@Martin Thank you, by the way. It was maddening.)

Comment: Strangely enough, ignored tags are shown (at least to me) only after I click on "edit" next to favorite tags. (Even after I add some tags.) I'll try to make some kind of answer. (BTW I'm glad to see that you come to meta at least occasionally.)

Comment: As a side note - I have edited the tags a bit, but I'll leave up to you whether or not to remove the tag ([meta-tag:bug]).

Comment: @Martin I removed it. The ones you added make definitely more sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior you describe seems to be consistent with having some tags among your [ignored tags](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/ignored-tags/info).

Many details about them can be found in the FAQ: [What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173) - I will quote some relevant parts.

> By default, questions with these tags are shown faded; they are still visible but less prominent. If you select *Hide questions in your ignored tags* in the *Tags* section of [`/users/preferences`](https://mathoverflow.net/users/preferences), they are hidden completely (this is done by a client-side script however, so you may notice odd “gaps”.)

There are several ways to add/remove ignored tags:

> - In the tag’s tooltip, click on the star twice (or once, if you have favoured that tag).
> - On the main page’s sidebar, click on *edit* next to *Favorite Tags.*
> - On [`/users/preferences`](https://mathoverflow.net/users/preferences), use the respective field in the *Tags* section.
>
> Note that [you can use wildcards](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/07/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/) in the latter two.

When you hover over any tag you are shown a tooltip. By repeatedly clicking on the star in the upper left corner you can toggle between none/favorite/ignored. (Correspondingly to these possibilities the star toggles between grey, gold and red cross.)

[image: Adding ignored tag via tooltip]

In the sidebar on the right [when viewing questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions) you should see list of favorite tags.

[image: sidebar]

When you click on the word edit, you can edit your favorite tags and your ignored tags. (It seems that ignored tags are not shown *until you click on edit*. But I did not find some documentation or a post on the main meta where this detail is explicitly spelled out.)

[image: sidebar after you click on edit]

And, as mentioned above, the third option is to [go to your profile](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=profile) and there choose "Edit Profile & Settings" and then "Preferences".

Comment: Thank you Martin!