# Why is an MO front-page question greyed out?

Tags: discussion, support, ignored-tags

Why is [symmetric monoidal double categories?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164227/symmetric-monoidal-double-categories) on the MO front page greyed out?
[image: picture of MO front page indicating greyed-out post]

Comment: Did you check whether your [ignored tags](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/ignored-tags/info) - whether some of them are used on the question? See also here: [Vanishing questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3378).

Comment: BTW I think that the tag ([meta-tag:support]) would be suitable here. And maybe also ([meta-tag:ignored-tags]) - if it is caused by ignored tags.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, I left off `support` because I thought I was reporting some strange site behaviour, not looking for support; but it turns out I *was* looking for support, because I'd somehow ignored `monoidal-categories`, and only that tag, without having any idea I'd done so.  (I didn't even know you could ignore tags.)  Thanks!  If you post [that](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4674/why-is-an-mo-front-page-question-greyed-out#comment23743_4674) as an answer, then I will accept it.

Comment: Actually, that would mean just duplicating my answer from the other question. (I think the best course of action is to close this as duplicate. Still, it might be useful to keep this on site - since depending on the search terms, this post might be easier to find than the other one.)

Comment: If I understood your [recommendation](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4674/why-is-an-mo-front-page-question-greyed-out#comment23746_4674) correctly, it is to close but not delete.  It seems that even the author can't unilaterally close, only vote to close, so I have done so.

Comment: I did not remember how exactly it works. Probably if I voted to close as duplicate *before* you, as the OP you could have closed the question. See also: [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981). (It is not really a problem, the question is in the [review queue](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/review/close/1594) and also at the top of the front page - so other users have several places where to notice that clove votes are needed here.)